# not found entity Order

Tags: apex

In a List, there are A, B 2 records.

A is a sales order and B is a return order.

How to lookup B to A when inserting List?

**A records**

```
    Order referenceOrderA = new Order();
    referenceOrderA.FID__c = '123abc';

    Order orderInfoA = new Order();
    orderInfoA.FID__c = '123abc';
    orderInfoA.Status = 'Draft';
    orderInfoA.EffectiveDate = System.today();

    OrderItem itemsA = new OrderItem();
    itemsA.Order = referenceOrderA;
    itemsA.UnitPrice = 50000;
    itemsA.Quantity= 20;
```

**B records**

```
Order referenceOrderB = new Order();
referenceOrderB.FID__c = '1234abcd';

Order orderInfoB = new Order();
orderInfoB.FID__c = '1234abcd';
orderInfoB.Status = 'Draft';
orderInfoB.EffectiveDate = System.today();
orderInfoB.oldOrder__r = referenceOrderA;

OrderItem itemsB = new OrderItem();
itemsB.Order = referenceOrderB;
itemsB.UnitPrice = 50000;
itemsB.Quantity= 20;
```

How to change

**OrderB.oldOrder__r = OrderA**?

This line of code will cause an exception

**orderInfoB.oldOrder__r = referenceOrderA**;

**A record may be after B record**

**For example: List [0] = B record, List [1] = A record.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code and context you've provided so far, what you are trying to do is impossible. The approach you're taking in your code needs to change.

With common usage, to be able to relate two records to one another, the parent record (record A, in your case) needs to have an Id so that you can populate the relationship field on record B (`oldOrder__c`).

I think what you were trying to achieve was [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm).

The key parts of doing that, however are:

- You need to set a value on a field defined as being an "external identifier" (it's a checkbox when you create/edit the field metadata on the object itself)
- The value of the external id field needs to be unique across all records of your given object
- There needs to be an existing record in the database (as opposed to in memory) with the external Id of the "parent" record
- The parent and child objects need to be different SObjects<sup>1</sup>
- The parent object must be inserted before the child object (i.e. it matters when you add each record to the `List<SObject>` you're DML-ing. Parent record *must* have a lower list index than any child record)

Trying to insert and relate parent and child records in a single DML statement just doesn't work if it's a self-relationship<sup>1</sup> (i.e. parent and child records are the same SObject type). The reason why it can work for inserting/relating different SObject types is because Salesforce breaks up DML operations on `List<SObject>` when the SObject type changes.

Since your question states that you're looking to do an insert for records A and B, it's safe to say that what you're trying to do is impossible. You will need to forego the fancy tricks and have two separate DML statements.

<sup>1: It is actually possible to insert and relate a parent-child pair for a self-relationship, but it requires that the parent and child records are inserted in separate trigger "chunks" (and the chunk containing the parent record needs to be executed first). You'd need to insert at least 201 records to make that happen. So, while this is technically possible, it's very impractical and relies on *very* specific circumstances.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The lookup itself is `__c`:

```
orderInfoB.oldOrder__c = referenceOrderA.Id;
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox    I tried orderInfoB.oldOrder__c = referenceOrderA.Id ;, but in debug, the field (orderInfoB.oldOrder__c) = null, Am i doing something wrong？